# can i change numbers of copy in printerviewcontroller ? if yes how?

Tags: swift, printing, uiactivityviewcontroller

i have a printing function in my app and i want to take number of copies by user but not tapping one by one because user can print it in bluk like thousand images in one go. if you can refer some tutorials and videos that describe solution of my problem. how can i do that? any help will appreciated.[image: it shows only one copy and increment one by one when tapping on plus icon]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of + and - you can use dropdown menu with a button click and in dropdown you can set what ever data you want.

Comment: it is by default functionality!